# R DateTime formatting

Tags: r, datetime

I have a field called `LunchTime` with the following values:
The format is `hh:mm`.

---

```
LunchTime 
1330
1330
1430
```

---

My anticipated result should be `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Though my code works when trying to return the results of the variable NAs show throughout the field.

```
FoodData$LunchTime <- strptime(FoodData$LunchTime , format = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")
```

Any ideas? I've tried using the `as.POSIXct` function, but unsure about the origin cause.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For the first one 2017-03-21 13:30:00. So it adds a date and the seconds to the time

Comment: Where does it get the day from?

Comment: Thats the date the log file was pulled from the system. Shouldve clarified that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In your posted example, your input data does does not include year, month, date, or seconds. Also, your example hour and minute are pasted next to each other with a colon (`:`).

If you change your format to be `"%H%M"` and match your example data, the code works. For example:

```
strptime(1330, format = "%H%M")
# [1] "2018-10-15 13:30:00 CDT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also like using `lubridate` to handle some of the parsing automatically.

```
Log_date_from_system <- as.Date("2018-10-15")

df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, text = "LunchTime
1330
1330
1430")


df$LunchTime2 <- lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(Log_date_from_system, df$LunchTime))
```